# Disable assertions in jar built with SBT, but enable in tests?

Tags: sbt

Building a Scala program with SBT, I want to disable assertions in the built JAR file, but I want to enable assertions during testing. This includes assertions stated in the main classes.
The obvious SBT keys are:

```
scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq(
    "-optimise", 
    "-Xelide-below", "3000", 
    "-Xdisable-assertions")
scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-optimise")
```

Unfortunately, this does not work: the JAR file indeed has assertions disabled, but so do the tests. For example, the ScalaTests

```
it("should have assertions enabled in test classes") {
  intercept[AssertionError] {
    Predef.assert(false, "Assertions are enabled in test classes")
  }
}

it("should have assertions enabled in main classes") {
  intercept[AssertionError] {
    MainClass.assertFalse
  }
}
```

both fail with the error: `Expected exception java.lang.AssertionError to be thrown, but no exception was thrown.`

Comment: I'm surprised that after 2 years, this problem is still not solved. How are people using assertions in their code then?

Answer (score 0):

The options in Test are appended to the options in Compile. To see its value, run `sbt "show test:scalac-options"`

To correct that, simply change your build to this:

```
 scalacOptions in Test := Seq("-optimise")
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only solves half of the problem. Indeed, now assertions are enabled in the test classes themselves (the first test succeeds).
The assertions in the main classes are still disabled, because they are compiled in the Compile phase with different flags. So the second test fails (ScalaTest should have assertions enabled in main classes).